# Is there a way to resolve the inner promise of this rxjs observable?

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs, discord.js, es6-promise

```js
(concat(ready$,processPlugins$) as Observable<{
        plugged: PluggedModule;
        cmdPluginsRes: {
            execute: Awaitable<Result<void, void>>;
            type: PluginType.Command;
            name: string;
            description: string;
        }[];
    }>)
```

```js
(concat(ready$,processPlugins$) as Observable<{
        plugged: PluggedModule;
        cmdPluginsRes: {
            execute: Result<void, void>;
            type: PluginType.Command;
            name: string;
            description: string;
        }[];
    }>)
```

^^ this above snippet is what I want. I just want to resolve `execute` in cmdPluginRes
so when I subscribe to the observable it would be easier to deal with the data.

i have this rxjs observable. Inside cmdPluginRes ( an array ), I have a promiseLike property execute. How could i turn this inner promise into its resolved type Result<void,void> ?
Result type comes from vultix ts-results.

Comment: You can pipe the observable into switchMap which will accept an async function and  process it in the pipe.

Comment: Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
concat(ready$, processPlugins$).pipe(
    switchMap(obj => from(obj.cmdPluginRes.execute).pipe(
        map(executeResult => ({...obj, execute: executeResult })
    ))
);
```

Here we pipe the emission into `switchMap`.

`switchMap` receives emissions and transforms them to emissions of an "inner observable", which in this case is your "execute" promise.

We use `from` to transform the promise to observable, which we can then `map` to a copy of the original object with the `execute` property replaced with the result.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Edit : since obj.cmdPluginRes was an array, i had to do this change : from(Promise.all(obj.cmdPluginRes.map(e=>e.execute))